# Which of the following lacks DNA?

Tags: zoology, homework

a) An Enucleated ovum
b) Mature RBC
c) A mature spermatozoan
d) Hair root

According to me, there can be 2 answers, a and b because an ovum whose nucleus has been removed lacks DNA. And also, initially RBC has a nucleus but as it matures it's nucleus disappears. So, mature RBC should also lack DNA. Then which one will be a more appropriate answer ?

Comment: If it's a mild trick question, then note that it doesn't say "genomic DNA" but "DNA". Enucleated ova would still have mitochondrial DNA, while mature RBC would not.

Comment: This should not be closed - OP has *clearly* attempted to answer and justified it!

Comment: @layork - nice  one - write it up as an answer - +1 from me :-)

Comment: @iayork Thank You. I understood it. You can post this as an answer.

Comment: It should be closed! It's not a question about biology it's a stupid MCQ. it's no use to anyone else than the questioner to have it here. It's the sort of rubbish that demeans this SE.

Comment: Further to my last, I have posted a proposal on the Meta site to automatically disallow MCQs. Those who find this acceptable are asked to argue their case at: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/change-homework-policy-to-disallow-multiple-choice-questions-mcqs

Comment: One last comment. How could the moderators react constructively to an MCQ under my proposed ban? In this case they could rephrase the question as something like "Are there any cells in the human body that lack DNA? I can think of two..." This would transform a specific a, b, c or d MCQ into a general biological discussion.

Comment: its a tricky one but the answer of mitochondrial genes may help us to eliminate the option of enucleated ovum and we can go for rbc

Comment: I agree with @David. Although, the asker has attempted to find an answer, questions like this are not useful. They are not straightforward questions about biological facts and are primarily intended to confuse the students (or test their ability to read the question carefully instead of actually testing the knowledge).

Answer (score 11):

There are two answers if the question refers to genomic DNA (neither enucleated ova nor mature RBCs have genomic DNA).  However, since the question *doesn't* specify genomic DNA, we can exclude enucleated ova, which would still have mitochondria and therefore mitochondrial genomic DNA.  Mature RBCS (at least in most mammals) [do not have mitochondria](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21698761), so the safest answer is probably b) Mature RBC.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 2) mature human RBCs don't have DNA. With the maturation of human red blood cells, the nucleus disappear. DNA is located in the nucleus so mature human RBCs don't have DNA.

However, your question didn't say "human RBC". Bird RBC have nucleus thus have DNA.

Then, both ovum and sperm cells have nucleus, thus have DNA, no matter which stage they are in.

I would say the possible answer be 4) hair root. The question didn't make it clear whether it's referring to the hair root cells or something else. But I would say that hair root is not made of body cells. No cell, no nucleus, no DNA.

Answer (score -1):

the answer will be mature DNA.
We know that except for nucleus other organelle such as mitochondria also have ability to replicate an as mentioned in the question the enucleated ovum (ovum lacking its nucleus) do have the other cell organelles, whereas for the mature erythrocytes, they lack nucleus as well as other cell organelles such as mitochondria and golgi bodies; and hence RBC can't divide on its.
hope it helps!

Comment: You are repeating the point made by an existing answer. If you have a new point to add then please [edit] your answer accordingly.